# Imitate poster typography

Tags: typography, kerning

So I am trying to recreate the following poster (or something similar)

[image]

My problem is obtaining the right typography and spacing. In particular I am having problems finding a good way to avoid hyphens. Bear with me, I have to show my efforts and where my solution diverges.

Sorry for the bad resolution but that is some of the reason why I want to improve it. I used the following background image

[image]

Using `\textbodyOriginal` defined as

```
\newcommand{\textbodyOriginal{%
[...]
\enquote*{sh}, they went with the \enquote*{ck} sound, which in classical
Greek  is  written  the  chi  symbol,  $\chi$.  This  was  later
translated into Latin, the chi ($\chi$) was replaced with the more common Latin $x$.
}
```

I created the following poster

[image]

By comparison with the original text, the first 9 lines agree. 
However, starting with the line `Greek [...] trans-` the spacing diverges
as LaTeX inserts an (unwanted) hyphen. I tried to fix this by introducing

the new command `\textbody` defined as

```
\newcommand{\textbody{%
[...]
\enquote*{sh}, \, they went with the \enquote*{ck} sound, which in classical \\
Greek \ph is \ph written \ph the \ph chi \ph symbol, \ph $\chi$. \ph This \ph was \ph later
\mbox{translated} into Latin, the chi ($\chi$) was replaced with the
\\ \centerline{more common Latin $x$.}
}
```

Where `\newcommand{\ph}{\hspace{0.1em}}` inserts some extra space.

I obtain

[image]

Now the kerning is almost right, however under closer inspection it is slightly unneven, and the spacing after `"Shi",` is of course too big compared to the rest of the line.

## Question

- Is there a way to produce the same text output as in the first image. As in the same words per line (I did this in my last image), but in a better way?

In addition my margins feels off, the top and bottom margin seems bigger than my side margins (Even though I have used `\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}` which should make them even?). However, I will perhaps save this question for later =)

## Code

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
%\usepackage[marigins=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{%
    linecolor=white,
    backgroundcolor=none,
    align=center,
    outerlinewidth=2pt,
    innertopmargin=20pt,
    innerbottommargin=20pt,
    innerrightmargin=20pt,
    innerleftmargin=20pt
}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}

\newcommand{\ph}{\hspace{0.1em}}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newcommand{\titleSymbol}{$x$}
\newcommand{\titleText}{Sheen}
\newcommand{\textbody}{%
    Algebra was born in the Middle East, during the Golden 
    Age of medieval Islamic civilization. During this heyday, 
    Muslim rule and culture had expanded onto the liberian
    Peninsula, where the Moors encouraged scholarship in 
    the sciences and math. The use of \enquote*{x} in this way began 
    with the inability of Spanish scholars to translate certain 
    Arabic sounds, including the letter sheen (or shin). But 
    since Spanish scholars had no corresponding sound for 
    \enquote*{sh}, \, they went with the \enquote*{ck} sound, which in classical \\
    Greek \ph is \ph written \ph the \ph chi \ph symbol, \ph $\chi$. \ph This \ph was \ph later
    \mbox{translated} into Latin, the chi ($\chi$) was replaced with the
    \\ \centerline{more common Latin $x$.}
}

\newcommand{\textbodyOriginal}{%
    Algebra was born in the Middle East, during the Golden 
    Age of medieval Islamic civilization. During this heyday, 
    Muslim rule and culture had expanded onto the liberian
    Peninsula, where the Moors encouraged scholarship in 
    the sciences and math. The use of \enquote*{x} in this way began 
    with the inability  of Spanish scholars to translate certain 
    Arabic sounds, including the letter sheen (or shin). But 
    since Spanish scholars had no corresponding sound for 
    \enquote*{sh}, they went with the \enquote*{ck} sound, which in classical
    Greek  is  written  the  chi  symbol,  $\chi$.  This  was  later
    translated into Latin, the chi ($\chi$) was replaced with the more common Latin $x$.
}

\begin{document}
 \pagecolor{green!10!black}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
    \node[opacity=0.25,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{mathMain}};
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{mdframed}[style=MyFrame]
\color{white}
{\centering

    \vspace{2cm}

    {\fontsize{300}{240}\selectfont \titleSymbol } 

    \vspace{2cm}

    {\Huge \bfseries Sheen } 

}
\LARGE%
\textbody 
%\textbodyOriginal
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's because the `\sfcode` (space factor) for the `.` is larger than for a normal space, so that end-of-sentence spaces may stretch more. You can disable that using `\frenchspacing`.

Comment: The original `x` lokks like the one from TeX-Gyre Termes (a Times clone).